# algorithm to find optimal x y index such that the sum of points in each quadrant is minimized

Tags: algorithm, matrix, optimization

I have a 2D array that contains various data points. Refer to Fig 1.
I need to split it into 4 quadrants in a such way that the sum of all points within each quadrant is minimized. The minimum size of each quadrant is 4x4, it can be greater but not less and it doesn't have to be a square necessarily. An optimal quadrant could have the size of 5x3 for example.

[image]

I need to find optimal index x and y that will lead to quadrants that minimal sums within them.

I see at as weight distribution problem. I can add all the values in my 2D array and I get sum, S. Now I need to more or less equally distribute that sum S across 4 quadrants. I know I have mentioned that the sum of each quadrant has to be the minimal possible, but it's more like balanced minimum.

Comment: Obviously, the total sum is going to be the same no matter where you split it, so by "balanced minimum" do you mean to minimize the difference between the max and min quadrants?

Comment: right, the sums for each quadrant should be fairly close to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sum the values in each quadrant efficiently using a [Summed Area Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table). This is a matrix with the same dimensions as your matrix where `table[i][j]` is the sum of all elements in the original matrix across from rows 0 to i and columns 0 to j.

You can calculate it like this (pseudo code):

```
for i = 0 to rows
    row_sum = 0
    for j = 0 to columns
        row_sum += matrix[i][j]
        table[i][j] = row_sum
        if i > 0
            table[i][j] += table[i-1][j]
```

The above code keeps a running sum across each row, and adds it to the table entry from the previous row at the same column.

Then you can use this table to calculate the value of each quadrant, for a given split. Suppose you want to split into quadrants horizontally after row i and vertically after column j, and the quadrants are like this:

```
a | b
--+--
c | d
```

You can calculate the quadrant sums like this:

```
a = table[i][j]
b = table[i][columns-1] - a
c = table[rows-1][j] - a
d = table[rows-1][columns-1] - (a + b + c)
```

So, you can iterate over the matrix and calculate the sums of the quadrants for every possible splitting location using 4 table lookups and some simple addition and subtraction. Keep track of the most optimal (according to your criteria, e.g. smallest difference between min quadrant and max) and that's your answer.

It's O(n) on the number of elements in the matrix.